# MongoRepository doesn't associate nested object with the class where is declared

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm having some troubles with the MongoRepository when I try to execute a post to the FlightClass service.

So, I have a class `Catering`

```
@NoArgsConstructor @Getter @Setter @ToString
@Document(collection = "catering")
public class Catering {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String title;

    public Catering(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

and another class `FlightClass`.

```
@NoArgsConstructor @Getter @Setter @ToString
@Document(collection = "flight-class")
public class FlightClass {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String title;

    @DBRef
    private Catering catering;
}
```

I declared my repository as follows:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "classes", path = "classes")
public interface FlightClassRepository extends 
    MongoRepository<FlightClass, String> {
}
```

But I'm having an issue when I try to do a `POST`

```
{
    "title": "Classic",
    "catering": {
        "id": <some_id_that_already_exists>
    }
}
```

And for some reason, spring-data doesn't associate the current record with the catering one.

The most bizarre thing is that I created a controller like the one below and it works.

```
@PostMapping("/flight-classes")
public ResponseEntity<FlightClass> post(@RequestBody FlightClass flightClass) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(flightClassRepository.insert(flightClass), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

Is this a bug in the Mongo repository? Or Am I doing something wrong?

These are my dependencies

```
...
dependencies {
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
runtimeOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
}
```

Does someone have an idea of why is this happening?

**I will like just to clarify that I'm not trying to do saving in cascade (I'm aware that this is not supported yet by the framework). I've already created an instance of catering. I was just hoping to associate it with a class**

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in this [link](https://juliuskrah.com/blog/2017/05/18/crud-operations-on-mongodb-with-spring-data/)
more specific in this two lines

```
flightClass.setCatering(Stream.of(yourObjectfindByID).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
flightClassRepo.save(flightClass);
```

Comment: Hi @Albert, my question is why if I'm using the annotation `@RepositoryRestResource` I'm not able to perform a POST request sending the nested object catering.